# Expand and Shrink on ellipsis click

Tags: javascript

So I have a comments section within one of my widgets that I would like to incorporate '**On ellipsis click, expand and shrink text**' but I'm having some issues targeting things such as:

1. Cut off after certain amount of words
2. Words not wrapping with the body.

Here is how the comments currently look:

[image]

My attempt looks like this

[image]

```js
function RevealHiddenOverflow(d) {
  if (d.style.overflow == "hidden") {
    d.style.overflow = "visible";
  } else {
    d.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="image-gallery">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 image">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <p class="truncate" onclick="RevealHiddenOverflow(this)" style="text-align: center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS

Comment: need to alter the CSS to wrap....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is the `white-space: nowrap;` is forcing it to one line. You can either alter that like you do visibility, or better yet, just toggle the class on click to remove/add it.

```js
function RevealHiddenOverflow(d) {
  d.classList.toggle("truncate")
}
```

```css
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="image-gallery">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 image">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <p class="truncate" onclick="RevealHiddenOverflow(this)" style="text-align: center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```